# How to choose rootViewController for App launch depending on a condition?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, segue

I have an app whereby i show my first view controller when the app is first installed. after the second run i dont want the first view to show any more.

I have saved a setting value that tells me if the app has been run before or not and if it has then i call performSegueWithIdentifier.

I cant call this in the viewDidLoad as this doesnt work but if i call it in the viewDidAppear then i see the first view for a split second.

Is there somewhere i can call this before the first view is even processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in your `AppDelegate.m`.

Check if the app has launched before, and set your `window` `rootViewController` accordingly.

```
-(void) setRootViewControllerByCheckingLoginStatus
{
    BOOL isUserLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IS_USER_LOGGEDIN"];

    if (isUserLogin) {

        // Set your controller if user has logged in.
        YourController *yourController = [[YourController alloc] init]; // Or YourController *yourController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourControllerStoryBoardID"];
        self.window.rootViewController = yourController;
    }
    else
    {
      //set other controller if user is not logged in. Or just let it be what it is by default.
    }
}
```

Call the above method in your `-application:
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

And you are done.

**EDIT for your comment..**

Black screen means you have not instantiated your ViewController correctly. dont use

```
[[YourController alloc] init];
```

Use

```
 YourController *yourController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourControllerStoryBoardID"];
```

Comment: Hi Mayur, i have implemented the abovehowever i get a black screen when running as if the view hasnt loaded??

Comment: it errors with storyboard and wants me to stick UIStoryBoard. using self.storyboard does not work, where do i get the instance of the story board from?

Comment: [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];